# Xcode Generate Code Coverage Report fails with Error : Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=14 "Failed to merge raw profiles in directory

Tags: xcode, code-coverage, xcode10, xcrun

I am unable to generate the code coverage data when the the workspace is built with custom XCODE_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR.

We run the xcodebuild commands to build the workspace with a XCODE_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR, so that multiple jenkins CI jobs won't overwrite the build output of other jobs which are also running concurrently.

When we run the tests for a build generated this way and try to get the code coverage report, the command fails with the below error.

jenkins$ xcrun xccov view *.xccovreport

Errors:
Error Domain=IDEFoundationErrorDomain Code=14 "Failed to merge raw profiles in directory /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-buggtqumttnpjvejnbfhulhqcvno/Build/ProfileData/bff950eda0f75b2dbadb3ce08510474b4667ac82 to destination /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-buggtqumttnpjvejnbfhulhqcvno/Build/ProfileData/bff950eda0f75b2dbadb3ce08510474b4667ac82/Coverage.profdata: No profile data files were written to '/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-buggtqumttnpjvejnbfhulhqcvno/Build/ProfileData/bff950eda0f75b2dbadb3ce08510474b4667ac82'" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to merge raw profiles in directory /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-buggtqumttnpjvejnbfhulhqcvno/Build/ProfileData/bff950eda0f75b2dbadb3ce08510474b4667ac82 to destination /Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-buggtqumttnpjvejnbfhulhqcvno/Build/ProfileData/bff950eda0f75b2dbadb3ce08510474b4667ac82/Coverage.profdata: No profile data files were written to '/Users/jenkins/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXX-buggtqumttnpjvejnbfhulhqcvno/Build/ProfileData/bff950eda0f75b2dbadb3ce08510474b4667ac82'}

Version/Build:
Version 10.1 (10B61)

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread on [Github](https://github.com/SlatherOrg/slather/issues/194#issuecomment-384127863)

The issue was: generating coverage for a `Static Library` fails, but not for a  `Dynamic Library`.

So check if it works, changing on pbxproj:

```
- MACH_O_TYPE = staticlib;
+ MACH_O_TYPE = mh_dylib;
```

[image]

And it really generated coverage successfully on my sample framework.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me was, I have changed the *Mach-O-Type from Executable to Static Library.*

1. With the option **Dynamic Library** also, the coverage report was generating but the build was failing.
2. Another option was to set the test target as **Static Library** and Main Target as **Executable**. Build Succeeded and able to see the coverage for multiple targets.

Xcode Version : 13.4

[image]