# Xcode code coverage failing with following warning Showing Recent Messages Failed to merge raw profiles in directory

Tags: swift, xcode, code-coverage

Have been unable to generate code coverage for over a week.  Have tried:  Rebooting & Relaunching Xcode.  Deleting the derived data folder.

Just noticed this warning:
Showing Recent Messages
Failed to merge raw profiles in directory /Users/e..l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Picman-dfefadmrrtyfcfduazopvkoniydf/Build/ProfileData/00008027-001221043EE9802E to destination /Users/e..l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Picman-dfefadmrrtyfcfduazopvkoniydf/Build/ProfileData/00008027-001221043EE9802E/Coverage.profdata: No profile data files were written to '/Users/e..l/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Picman-dfefadmrrtyfcfduazopvkoniydf/Build/ProfileData/00008027-001221043EE9802E'

Enable code coverage appears on and Gather Code coverage for all targets as well.  Editor shows code coverage.

Using Xcode 13.0 (13A233)

[image: Enable code coverage]

[image: Gather code coverage for all targets]

Comment: Report this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Has there been any feedback or resolution for this?

Answer (score -2):

Change the **Mach-O-Type** in the build settings to Static Library or Dynamic Library. It didn't worked when the type is Executable.

Please check this answer. I have faced the similar issue in Xcode 13.
Able to resolve it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74127882/10694277